# The error doesn't happen while importing in the local Database

Tags: java, mysql, heidisql

[image]I am importing json files into my database. I get the java.lang.NullPointerException for some files. On tracing the error, i see that the error occurs in the last_name column of the database. Some of the names are

> "Heldeweg, M.A.","Schlössels, R.J.N.","Seerden, R.J.G.H."

and the last names are

> Heldeweg, Schlössels, Seerden

which i extract from the names array.

But when I try to import the same files into the local database, they files get imported without any issues. I don't seem to know how to trace the error that is causing the java.lang.NullPointerException error.

I actually added a screenshot of the error. Could you tell me which part of the code to look at to identify the location of the error?

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: *I don't seem to know how to trace the error* and unless we can see your code, neither can we

Comment: @ScaryWombat i added a screenshot. would you pls be able to identify the portion of the error that points to the code.?

Comment: looks like a UTF8 encoding problem

Comment: but then that problem should happen while importing in the local db too, shouldn't it?